# Webpack-dev-server Bundle.js not found

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I launch webpack-dev-server and navigate to homepage at localhost:8000, everything works as normal. However, when I navigate to localhost:8000/app/home, the console indicates that bundle.js cannot be found. How should I deal with this?

Folder structure:

```
 dist/
  index.html
 app/
   js/
    homepage.jsx
    event.jsx 
    home.jsx
   css/
    style.css
   app.js
 webpack.config.js
```

index.html imports bundle with:

```
<script src="./bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: post your webpack config and the command you are running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an absolute path:

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

Otherwise, the client will request `/app/home/bundle.js`, which doesn't exist.